# 403 Forbidden while sending data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

It is neither issue of file permission nor existence of file.

While sending `formData` through `jquery` data is passing successfully, but when I try with pure `javascript` then it returns error `POST 403(Forbidden)`.

It is sure that problem is generated from `ckeditor` content. because if I pass following parameters

```
var heading = document.getElementById('heading').value;
var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
```

And pass as follow

```
http.send('heading='+heading+'&date='+date);
```

It returns no error, works fine.

But if I add following parameters

```
var content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
```

And pass as follow

```
http.send('heading='+heading+'&date='+date+'&content='+encodeURIComponent(content));
```

It returns error.

```
POST 403(Forbidden)
```

I think special characters that are inserted in textarea are the cause of problem. Because if variable `content` is empty there would no error. Jquery is passing data, but why forbidden issue while using javascript ?  I need to pass special characters without escaping. Because I can't control ckeditor output, becuase it is user input.

Comment: There is no way to tell based on your client-side code why your server is refusing a request.

Comment: Please check your server logs to find out the exact stacktrace is.